Undesired pagebreak in a list of tabularX
I am writing a list of articles, with their title and abstract, using tabularX. I would like them to be in a continuous list, breaking page whenever there is no space. I mean, I do not want each item "as a whole" moving to another page.
For example:
\begin{enumerate}

\item   
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{lX}
Title: & This title \\
Abstract: & \lipsum[1]
\end{tabularx}

\item   
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{lX}
Title: & This title \\
Abstract & \lipsum[4-7]
\end{tabularx}


\end{enumerate}

creates the first item in one page, and the second in another page. I would like the second item to start after the first one, and the line break to happen "within" the abstract.
I cannot use longtable (right?), because I would lose the benefits of using tabularx for the width of the colummns. Or is it the "enumerate" which forbids the linebreaks?
Does anybody know how to do this?
Thank you.

you have not provided any code we can run but are not all those tabularx too wide and sticking in the margin?  there are lots or packages that give X column functionality to longtable, but then again almost all tables set with lX are really not tables at all and are better set as a list.

you can not break within a table row, so you _definitely-) want to use a list here.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

use a description list instead of tabularx.

As pointed out in comments, {tabularx} is not quite the right tool for this. Nested {enumerate} and {description} work far better. In the following example the first block corresponds to the default behaviour, while the second one uses enumitem to have the same margin for both title and abstract. (I prefer the first one.)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{description}
\item[Title] This title
\item[Abstract] \lipsum[1]
\end{description}
\item
\begin{description}[labelwidth=6em,leftmargin=6em,labelsep=0pt]
\item[Title] This title
\item[Abstract] \lipsum*[4-7]
\end{description}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}



Thank you. This does nicely.
